# Unknown column with DB connection

Tags: grails

I am new to Grails. When I am trying to connect to MySQL from grails I am getting the error **Unknown column 'this_.version' in 'field list'**. I do not have any such column in my table. Could any one please help to understand?

Answer (score 1):

**id** and **version** columns are created by default for each domain class mapped in db.

If you do not want it try this code (just check mapping section) for your Test domain class:

```
Class Test {
    String testName

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }
}
```